# ERROR: Client found response content type of 'multipart/related C# asmx client

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx, svc

I'm trying to create a web service client (asmx), connected to web service(.svc) from another host. I used add web reference that generating the service classes in the project. However, when I call the getData() for example, Im getting this error :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Client found response content type of 'multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>";boundary="uuid:*****************+id=1";start-info="text/xml"', but expected 'text/xml'.

The request failed with the error message:

--



--uuid:********************+id=1

Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"



<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/fault</a:Action><a:FaultDetail><a:ProblemHeaderQName>a:Action</a:ProblemHeaderQName></a:FaultDetail></s:Header><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode>a:ActionMismatch</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://tempuri.org/ICustomService/GetData'. </faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>

--uuid:***************************+id=1--
```

I tried with the soapUI. It's working fine and this is the RAW response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="<http://tempuri.org/0>;"start-info="text/xml"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--uuid:****************
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit
Content-Type:application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text-xml"

<s:Envelope............
```

**By the way**, the service url is added automatically inside **applicationSettings** tag
eg.

```
<applicatonSettings>
   <my_service.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="my_service.serviceInquriy.CustomService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://serviceurl/serviceInquriy.svc</value>
        </setting>
   </my_service.Properties.Settings>
</applicatonSettings>
```